# Multiple words with same definition

Tags: words, nuances, wago-and-kango

I am seeing pairs of words with similar meanings (where one of the words has a single kanji and the other has two kanji).

Examples include:
豊か、豊富
保つ、保存する
防ぐ、予防する

Do these pair of words share the same meaning? If so, what is the point of having multiple words with the same meaning?

Comment: deep vs. profound, sweat vs. perspire, chat vs. converse, etc.  What's the point?

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36422/%e6%a8%aa%e6%96%ad%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%a8-%e6%a8%aa%e5%88%87%e3%82%8b-%e3%81%ae%e9%81%95%e3%81%84/36428#36428